# Why is my company_url variable not being defined?

Tags: python-3.x, function, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the rank, name and url of a company from a website. This involves two pages and I have nested functions to get all the information I need. However, when I try to print the details I get an error that the company_url variable is not defined. I thought that calling the company_button_url function within the main function would do the job, but something is wrong. I have tried calling company_button_url() at differing points in the code, but cannot get it to work.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Handle 403- Forbidden Error
url = 'https://www.b.co.uk/the-lists/mid-companies/'
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})

html = urlopen(req).read()
html_page = html.decode('utf-8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser') # create soup object

'''Main Function'''
def company_details():
    
    # find rank
    rank = soup.find('div', class_="company-score-redesign").text

    # find company name
    company_name = soup.find('div', class_="company-name-redesign").text

    # find company website
    ''' Find Button Url...Parse HTML from new Url...Find Company Website '''
    def company_button_url():
        comp = soup.find('div', class_="company-name-redesign-mobile")
        comp_btn = comp.find('a', href = True)
        comp_btn_url = comp_btn['href']
        new_url = comp_btn_url
        # Handle 403- Forbidden Error
        new_req = Request(new_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})
        nhtml = urlopen(new_req).read() # Getting new page
        nhtml_page = nhtml.decode('utf-8')
        
        nsoup = BeautifulSoup(nhtml_page, 'html.parser') # create new soup object

        div_company_url = nsoup.find('div', class_="profile-info")
        href_company_url = div_company_url.find('a', href = True)
        company_url = href_company_url['href']
        return company_url

    company_button_url()
    print(rank, company_name, company_url)

    return()

company_details()
```

Feel very free to pull my coding to pieces - I am very new to this!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read more about Python variable scoping https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Comment: because you return `company_url` but dont store it globally so it is only valid inside the  `company_button_url` function, to fix this, you can do `company_url = company_button_url()` just above your print statement.

Comment: Also as @PavloZhukov  suggested, you might do yourself a favour by learning a bit about global and local scopes of variables in python because I can see it causing you more problems in future.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Your solution was very helpful, @BijayRegmi